# DOMDocument grab html between two p tags

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am currently learning PHP DOM. I am pulling data off a webpage and attempting to parse it on my page.  My question is how can I grab the HTML? With this method below, it grabs all text and strips the HTML. I am wanting to leave the HTML in place.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://websiteaddress.com");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHtml($html);
$x = new DOMXpath($doc);
foreach ($x->query("//h3[@class='expressway full-width']//p") as $node)
{
    $title[] = trim($node->textContent);
}
```

I am wanting something like $node->htmlContent - but this does not seem to exist.

**EDIT:**

I have attempted the answer to the linked question, however it does not work for me:

```
$location[] = trim($node->saveHtml($x));
```

shows:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::saveHtml() in /home/****/public_html/bluegrass_jobs.php on line 34
```

Comment: How you initialized `$x`?

Comment: Yes all works will with the code above. It simply strips HTML and I am wanting to preserve it.

Comment: `saveHtml()`? I see `loadHtml()` everywhere. You may want to try that one.

Comment: @Jesse Now I am really confused... I used loadHTML at the beggining: $doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHtml($html);
$x = new DOMXpath($doc); and now your asking me to use it like this: $location[] = trim($node->loadHTML($x));? Like I say I am new to DOM, so please explain.

Comment: Oh! I see, the linked answer says `saveXml()` (**Xml**, not Html), and you're using `saveHtml()`.

Comment: @Jesse I have also tried that. I get the same error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::saveXml() in /home/****/public_html/bluegrass_jobs.php on line 34

Comment: Actually, try this: `$doc->saveHtml($node)`. That should work.